# Error "A dependent dll was not found" in C++/WinRT project while using OpenSSL-1.1.1g

Tags: openssl, windows-runtime

I would like to use [OpenSSL-1.1.1g](ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz) in a [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/) project. So i created a [test project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PiLx3rNqe7vwRBkhjLtGwj4-mT24LU94/view?usp=sharing). The below is what did i do in this project:

> 1.Install [C++/WinRT](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CppWinRTTeam.cppwinrt101804264) in VS2019

> 2.Create project "TestOpenSSL1.1.1g" in the directory "c:\temp" (File->New->Project->Blank App(C++/WinRT))

> 3.Install [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/)  and [NASM](https://www.nasm.us/)

> 4.Download [OpenSSL-1.1.1g](ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1g.tar.gz) and extract it to "c:\temp\openssl-1.1.1g"

> 5.Open "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019" with "Run as Administrator"

> 6.Enter the directory "openssl-1.1.1g"
>
> > cd c:\temp\openssl-1.1.1g

> 7.Configure openssl
>
> > perl configure VC-WIN32 --prefix="c:\temp\TestOpenSSL1.1.1g\openssl-1.1.1g"

> 8.Compile openssl
>
> > nmake

> 9.Install openssl
>
> > nmake install

> 10.So i saw the directories "bin" "html" "include" "lib" were created in "c:\temp\TestOpenSSL1.1.1g\openssl-1.1.1g"

> 11.Include openssl header files
>
> > Add "$(ProjectDir)..\openssl-1.1.1g\include" in Solution Explorer->Properties->Configuration properties->C/C++ ->General->Additional include directories

> 12.Add dependencies "libcrypto.lib" and "libssl.lib"
>
> > Add "$(ProjectDir)..\openssl-1.1.1g\lib\libcrypto.lib;$(ProjectDir)..\openssl-1.1.1g\lib\libssl.lib" in Solution Explorer->Properties->Configuration properties->Linker->Input->Additional dependencies

> 13.Modify MainPage.cpp
>
> > #include <openssl/ssl.h>

> > Add statement "OPENSSL_init();" in function "MainPage::MainPage";

After all these I built [this project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PiLx3rNqe7vwRBkhjLtGwj4-mT24LU94/view?usp=sharing), there was no error. but if i debug this project the errors came:[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after using the source codes from [openssl](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) and configuring with command "[perl Configure VC-WIN32-UWP](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES-Windows.txt)"